# pqxx not found using CMake

Tags: c++, postgresql, cmake, libpqxx

I have some pqxx-related packages installed on my Ubuntu 19.04, and [this (official C++ PostgreSQL Client)](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx)  in my CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, and libpqxx-config.cmake in my CMAKE_MODULE_PATH (and CMAKE_MODULE_PATH set respectively) /lib/cmake.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
find_package(libpqxx REQUIRED)
message(STATUS ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
add_executable(example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC libpqxx)
```

main.cpp:

```
...
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
...
```

...and my GCC produces the following:

```
fatal error: pqxx/pqxx: No such file or directory
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
```

Now, ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS} contains strange
`/usr/include/postgresql/usr/include/postgresql/10/server` 
instead of path to libpqxx in my prefix.

Output of sudo aptitude search "~npqxx" for already installed in the system pqxx-stuff:

```
p  libpqxx-3.1 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL
p  libpqxx-3.1:i386 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL
p  libpqxx-3.1-dbg - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (debugging symbols)
p  libpqxx-3.1-dbg:i386 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (debugging symbols)
p  libpqxx-4.0 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL
p  libpqxx-4.0:i386 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL
p  libpqxx-dbg - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (debugging symbols)
p  libpqxx-dbg:i386 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (debugging symbols)
p  libpqxx-dev - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (development files)
p  libpqxx-dev:i386 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (development files)
p  libpqxx-doc - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (documentation)
p  libpqxx3-dev - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (development files)
p  libpqxx3-dev:i386 - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (development files)
p  libpqxx3-doc - C++ library to connect to PostgreSQL (documentation)
```

As I suppose, the thing is CMake somehow gave priority to the system internals instead of libpqxx CMake package. But prefixed one seems to be properly installed and I have no clue about reasons of so strange behaviour.

libpqxx installation protocol:

```
git clone https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=... -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=.../lib/cmake
make -j16 && make install
```

How can I make libpqxx visible and usable now?

Comment: For finding a CMake configuration file (e.g. `libpqxx-config.cmake`), you should set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, not `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Comment: Is not my libpqxx a CMake module to provide visibility for it by enabling CMAKE_MODULE_PATH? Where can I read about that difference between CMAKE_{PREFIX|MODULE}_PATH?

Comment: CMake modules (using `FindXXX.cmake` files) are provided by CMake itself, and you can use `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to tell CMake to look for additional modules elsewhere also. You have a `XXX-config.cmake` file, which would be found via Config search mode, not Module mode. You can read about the differences between CMake Module search and CMake Config search modes in the [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature-and-module-mode) documentation.

Comment: You output value of `PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable but otherwise don't use it. I see no `include_directories` call which actually adds include directory.

Comment: 2Tsyvarev : is not target_link_libraries(..) call add all required relations too, e.g. include directories?